# mongoDB - how to link one embedded object to another embedded object

Tags: mongodb, nosql

**Background Information**

I'm trying my hand at my first mongoDB database.
So far, I've decided that I will need to use both references and embedded data models. One of the features of this application will allow users to track where ports on a network switch are mapped to.

**Example:**
Let's say I have switch "ABC" and "DEF".  Port a2 on ABC is linked to port d3 on DEF. On my web interface, when the user is viewing the details for switch ABC, I want to show that it's linked to DEF's port d3 using a selectable / clickable hyperlink.  When the clicks on it, I want to be able to show the details for switch DEF port d3.

**Question:**

I'm not sure what the best way is as far as design is concerned, to support this type of functionality.

**Model**

So far I have the following model in mind:

Switch types collection:

```
{  
   _id: "HP-ProCurve-5406zl",
   name: "HP ProCurve 5406zl",
   propertyX: valueX,
   propertyY: valueY
}  
{  
   _id: "switch-xyz",
   name: "The best switch ever",
   propertyX: valueX,
   propertyY: valueY
}
```

"network_switches" collection:

```
{
   _id: 12345,
   Name: "ABC",
   type_id: "HP-ProCurve-5406zl",
   ports: [ 
                {
                  port_name: "a1",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: 
                }
                {
                  port_name: "a2",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: 
                } 
                { 
                  port_name: "a3",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: 
                }

          ]
}


{
   _id: 12366,
   Name: "DEF",
   type_id: "switch-xyz",
   ports: [ 
                {
                  port_name: "a1",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: 
                }
                {
                  port_name: "d2",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: 
                } 
                { 
                  port_name: "d3",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: 
                }

          ]
}
```

**Possible Solution?**

I was thinking of assigning port ids in addition to names using the switch name.  So for sample, for the ABC switch, port "a1" should look like this:

```
                  port_id: "ABC-a1",
                  port_name: "a1",
```

And the d3 port on switch DEF would look like this:

```
                  port_id: "DEF-d3",
                  port_name: "d3",
```

That would then allow me to do something like this with the linked_port 
fields:

```
               {
                  port_id: "ABC-a1",
                  port_name: "a1",
                  visible_label: "",
                  interface_id: "1000Base-T",
                  L2_address: "",
                  linked_port: "DEF-d3"
                }
```

Before I commit to this, I wanted to make sure there were no glaring problems with this design. Is there a way in mongo for me to find this DEF object by querying using the port id?

Any comments?

Comment: Maybe split the linked_port information for easier querying =>  linked_port : { switch : "DEF", port : "d3" }.  port_id is not necessary that way, unless you really want to give it a combined name.   Search : db.network_switches.find({"ports.linked_port.switch":"DEF"})

Comment: @aldwinaldwin ah!  I like that.  Do you think then I still need port_id?

Comment: It's a little bit redundant. But, it might make programming life little easier to search on that field instead on combined fields. Some people like redundancy, others are alergic to unneccesary data. ... In the end, you can still add it to all existing documents if needed. There probably won't be 50.000.000 switches/documents to update.